# Como criar registros na tabela MYSQL de acordo com o valor da variável $nregistros PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis, sql-insert

Tenho uma variável $nregistros que define o valor de registros a ser inserido na tabela "formularios".

Se o $nregistros for igual a 4 por exemplo, ele deve inserir 4 linhas da seguinte forma:

```
formularios
id|campo
6 | 1
7 | 2
8 | 3
9 | 4
```

o campo "id" é autoindex, e o campo "campo" deve iniciar em 1 e ir até o valor final da $nregistros, no caso aqui, 4

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esse feito, um simples `for` pode resolver.

Tente algo como :

```
<?php
    $nregistros = 4;
    for($n = 1; $n <= $nregistros; $n++) {       
        echo "INSERT INTO formularios SET campo = $n; ";
    }
?>
```

No lugar do `echo` entraria sua query de inserção no banco.

Dessa forma, obtive a seguinte saída:

```
INSERT INTO formularios SET campo = 1; INSERT INTO formularios SET campo = 2; INSERT INTO formularios SET campo = 3; INSERT INTO formularios SET campo = 4;
```

> Vale lembrar que caso o número que estiver na variável `$nregistros`
>   for muito longo, haverá perda de performance, pelo fato da realização
>   de múltiplos `insert`.

Comment: isso mesmo que precisava, valeu!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado. :)